# How to handle queries in REST API [ python]

Tags: python, rest, falconframework

I learning how to implement REST API's in python using falcon lib. 
For example I have the following dict:

```
db_data = {
    "servers" : {
        "1": {
            # 'server_id':1,
            "plugins":{
                "1": {
                    "metrics_by_time":{
                        "2014":{"1":"Hello World 0"}
                        "2015":{"1":"Hello World 1"}
                        "2016":{"1":"Hello World 2"}
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I  want to create an API that will return to return metrics by a period of time (for example between 2014 and 2016). How could I do it? 
For example I have now the following code that returns metrics by server_id and plugin_id:

```
class By_Plugin_ID(object):
      def on_get(self, req, resp, server_id, plugin_id):
           resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
           resp.body = (json.dumps(db_data["servers"][str(server_id)]["plugins"][str(plugin_id)], ensure_ascii=False, default=lambda x:str(x)))
import falcon
app = application = falcon.API()
plugins_metrics = By_Plugin_ID()
app.add_route('/metrics/{server_id}/{plugin_id}', plugins_metrics)
```

I thought about something like this, but how to handle the queries after "?" :

```
metrics/{server_id}/{plugin_id}?from_time={timestamp}&to_time={timestamp}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Falcon, I usually work with Flask, however looking at their documentation you should get them with  req.get_param()

```
from_time = req.get_param('from_time')
to_time = req.get_param('to_time')
```

you should put this in your `on_get()` function

```
def on_get(self, req, resp, server_id, plugin_id):
    from_time = req.get_param('from_time')
    to_time = req.get_param('to_time')
    # do whatever you want and return your response
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `?` come the query parameters. Falcon let's you access them using [`Request.params`](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/request_and_response.html#Request.params).